# ASP.Net Resource Strings in Link format display

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

The requirement goes this way. I have localized strings in my asp.net web application. I have a aspx page. Consider there is a string key-value pair in the resource file. The value is translated in different languages and available in different resource files. Ex: Strings.fr-FR.resx. Consider the value in resource file is "Hello World", that is translated to different languages.

In my aspx page, I want to retrieve the string from the resource file and display it in the page. But, I want "World" only to be in link format. How can i do it? If I display entire string in an anchor tag , then entire word "Hello World" would be in link format.

Again, my question is how to display only "World" in link format after retrieving from the resource file.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normally you can't do that, if you need a specific string to be localized and you create a resource element for that purpose, than you should consider it as an atomic element. Therefore: create a hello resource item. 
If you really need to split that string you can call .ToString(), then .Split() on whitespace and finally take the second element with [1]. 
But I don't advise you to do this because some languages can have the word corrisponding to world as first word or even using a different number of words to say hello world. Even if you have only N languages, all translating 'hello world' with 2 words and having world as second word, I'd not do that because you are creating a strong relation between string form and its semantic, which is a source of bugs in case of new supported languages or string change.

Comment: Thanks Alberto. Your suggestion is valid and will surely consider it during the implementation phase.